# С помощью каких методов можно реализовать межпроцессное взаимодействие на С++

Tags: c++

Нужно реализовать данный алгоритм в С++.
1. запустить print.exe, которая ждет ввода данных оператором из консоли
2. запустить hello_world.exe, которая в цикле ожидает 10 минут прихода данных от   print.exe
3. вводишь строчку в коносли для print.exe
4. print.exe, используя механизм межпроцессного взаимодействия передает данные программе hello_world.exe
5. hello_world.exe выводит эту сточку в консоль
То есть какими методами можно перехватывать поток вывода одной программы в другую. Если есть пример реализации этих методов, то прошу их привести.

Comment: @PinkTux да, запускаемые программы имеют доступ к одной файловой системе.

Comment: Вообще говоря, это сильно зависит от используемой операционной системы... Например, в OS/2 (специально выбрал экзотику :)) это можно делать с помощью именованных семафоров и именованной общей памяти или, скажем, файлов, с помощью пайпов. Можно воспользоваться той же TCP/IP. Зависит от того, что у вас под рукой и каким критериям надо удовлетворить :) Стандартные средства C++ ограничиваются взаимодействиями между потоками. Ну, разве что через файлы...

Comment: [Выбирайте любой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Для обмена данными между приложениями Windows существует много механизмов: буфер обмена (Clipboard), технология COM, передача данных между окнами процессов с помощью сообщения WM_COPYDATA, удаленный вызов процедур (RPC), сокеты (Windows Sockets), динамический обмен данными (DDE), именованные каналы (Named Pipes), почтовый ящик (Mailslot) и проецируемые в память файлы (Mapped file). У каждого способа есть свои плюсы и минусы.